# How to listen to click event when scroll button is clicked using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to select the scroll button and assign it an attribute value when it is clicked. I am aware that pseudo elements cannot be selected in jQuery. Any workaround solution possible for this?

Comment: What is the relationship between scroll button and pseudo elements ?

Comment: Scroll button is a pseudo element or chrome element

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean mouse's middle button?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button

`$(window).on('click', function (e) {
    if (e.button === 1 || e.which === 2) {
        console.log('middle button');
    }
});`

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to scroll event on the element being scrolled.
Clicking scroll button will any way trigger scroll event.

Comment: The scroll event will also be triggered when the scrollbar track is dragged, in such case how to differentiate as to what triggered the scroll event?